# Can we add double click to table row in blueprintjs

Tags: javascript, blueprintjs

I'm using blueprintjs's table to populate data and want some method to be called on double-clicking the table row. Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as double click event. What you could do is create a variable which calls a function when the same button is pressed twice

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this by setting `interactive={true}` on the `Cell` and then wrapping the cell contents in a div with the double click event:

```
<Cell
  interactive={true}
>
  <div onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}>{...}</div>
</Cell>
```

Comment: You must pay attention and use a div element. Using a span won't work as expected, because it won't fill the cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can additionally bind double click event on row.
in javascript: use syntax

```
<p ondblclick="myFunction()">Double-click me</p>
```

in jquery:

```
$(row).on('dblclick', function() {
});
```

Comment: This happens in the DOM though. I think the question was about how this is done specifically with the blueprint table component.

Comment: i just suggest a way of doing it through javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

1. there is indeed a browser "dblclick" event
2. the Table does not currently support this. follow along at https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/1087